# Visual Foxpro 9.0

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have a programming problem in Visual FoxPro, create a form that contains PageFrame with 2 Page.
1. On Page 1, Create a program to display data in the grid and give the sorting facilities, navigation and search.
2. On Page 2, create a program to calculate volumeTabung and spacious blanket.
Can anyone provide a solution? thank you

Comment: Do my homework\job for me questions aren't the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not DOING the answer, but a simple guide.

In the VFP command window,

Create Form [whatever form name you want]

Once form is up, look at the toolbar for "Form Controls".  Click on the "PageFrame" control and then click on the form... There, you have a default pageframe with 2 pages as a default.

The "Properties" window should be visible by default.  Click on the combobox on at the top which shows all controls.  Open the drop-down and you will see "Page1" and "Page2" of the page frame control.  Click on either page, and that will bring focus to that respective page.

Now, click on the Forms Controls toolbar again, such as to grab textbox, label, combobox, whatever and then click on the page and your controls are there.  Then get focus to the second page and do the same for whatever you want.

Save and run the form. This just gets you to see the controls and how simple to put them on.  Actual pulling your data and populating is really more your "to do" list.